# c++ create a modified copy of an object inside its own class

Tags: c++, class

I need to create a class that every time an object is created, creates also a modified copy and is able to execute the same methods to give back the difference between the original and the modified.
I have created this example, but it does not work:

```
#include <iostream>

class Box
{
public:
    double l, w, h;
    double vol, surf;

    double getVol(){return l*w*h;};
    double getSurf(){return (l*w + l*h + w*h) *2;};
    double getVolDiff()
    {
        boxTemp->l = l+1;
        boxTemp->w = w;
        boxTemp->h = h;

        return getVol() - boxTemp->getVol();
    };
private:
        Box* boxTemp;

};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    Box box;
    box.l = 1;
    box.w = 2;
    box.h = 3;

    std::cout << "Vol: " << box.getVol() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Surf: " << box.getSurf() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Vol Diff: " << box.getVolDiff() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This example is giving me an error inside the method `getVolDiff`. Can you help me to solve this?

**EDIT**
Sorry if I had not specified the error, but it is a runtime error and I don't get any information from the compiler.

Comment: You never initialize `boxTemp`. You should write a constructor initializing all the class fields.

Comment: When you say "error", what do you mean by that? Build error? Runtime crash? Unexpected results? Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Once you initialize `boxTemp` with a new instance of `Box` make sure you won't end up with a recursive call.

Comment: And why do you need `boxTemp` as a member variable? Can't it be a *local* (non-pointer) variable in the function? Or why do you need it at all? Can't `getVolDiff` just return `getVol() - (l + 1) * w * h`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: If you are seeing a run-time crash, what do the available tools (e.g. `gdb`, `valgrind`) tell you about the source of the error?  (Clue: you never assign `boxTemp` a value).

Answer (score 2):

Dump the pointer if you haven't any good use for it and use a local box instead.

```
double getVolDiff() {
  Box boxTemp; // temp, no allocation

  boxTemp.l = l+1;
  boxTemp.w = w;
  boxTemp.h = h;

  return getVol() - boxTemp.getVol();
}
```

Adding a constructor would simplify you code a bit

```
Box(double l, double w, double h) : l(l), w(w), h(h) {}

double getVolDiff() {
  Box boxTemp(l+1, w, h); // temp, no allocation

  return getVol() - boxTemp.getVol();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly,**_instance** is for the orijinal object not changed(**Singleton**), also temp object(**boxTemp**) can be updated

```
 #include <iostream>

class Box
{
 public:

   double l, w, h;
   double vol, surf;

double getVol() { return l*w*h; };
double getSurf() { return (l*w + l*h + w*h) * 2; };
double getVolDiff()
{
    boxTemp->l = l + 1;
    boxTemp->w = w;
    boxTemp->h = h;

    return getVol() - boxTemp->getVol();
};

static Box* getInstance() {
    if (_instance == 0) {
        _instance = new Box;
    }
    return _instance;
}

void setTemp(Box *b1) {

    boxTemp = b1;
}

private:
    Box* boxTemp;
    static Box *_instance;
};

Box* Box::_instance = 0;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {


Box box;
box.l = 1;
box.w = 2;
box.h = 3;

std::cout << "Vol: " << box.getVol() << std::endl;
std::cout << "Surf: " << box.getSurf() << std::endl;

Box *orj = Box::getInstance();
orj->l = 4;
orj->w = 5;
orj->h = 6;

std::cout << "*** Vol: " << box.getVol() << std::endl;
std::cout << "*** Surf: " << box.getSurf() << std::endl;

orj->setTemp(&box);

std::cout << "Vol Diff: " << orj->getVolDiff() << std::endl;

return 0;
```

}